# AES 256 algorithm support

Tags: java, android, algorithm, encryption, cryptography

Is there anywhere a secure and trusted API that allows me to use the AES-256 algorithm in my Android application?

I have written a simple API using `javax.crypto` and `java.security` classes with JDK 9 that offers support for AES-256.
Because Android is still stuck with JDK 7 (JDK 8 doesn't support AES-256), I cannot use these API. So, how can I use encryption based on AES-256 algorithm?

Comment: Note that AES-128 is as secure as AES-256, that is both are secure.

Comment: Android has always had AES-256. Just use `Cipher.getInstance("AES/<mode>/PKCS5PADDING")` and use a 256-bit key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code given by dealforest on github from the following link: 
[AES256 encrypt android](https://gist.github.com/dealforest/1949873#file-aes256cipher-java)

I put the code below if you want to get it more easily ;)

```
    import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

    import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
    import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

    public class AES256Cipher {

        public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] ivBytes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] textBytes) 
                throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException, 
                    NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                    NoSuchPaddingException,
                    InvalidKeyException,
                    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
                    IllegalBlockSizeException,
                    BadPaddingException {

            AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
            SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = null;
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
            return cipher.doFinal(textBytes);
        }

        public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] ivBytes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] textBytes) 
                throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException, 
                NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                NoSuchPaddingException,
                InvalidKeyException,
                InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
                IllegalBlockSizeException,
                BadPaddingException {

            AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
            SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
            return cipher.doFinal(textBytes);
        }
    }
```

And here's how to use the class:

```
    String key = "e8ffc7e56311679f12b6fc91aa77a5eb";
    byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] ivBytes = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

    String plainText;
    byte[] cipherData;
    String base64Text;

    //############## Request(crypt) ##############
    plainText  = "crypt text!!";
    cipherData = AES256Cipher.encrypt(ivBytes, keyBytes, plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    base64Text = Base64.encodeToString(cipherData, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.d("encrypt", base64Text);

    //############## Response(decrypt) ##############
    base64Text = "72XrlydqnUzVrDfDE7ncnQ==";
    cipherData = AES256Cipher.decrypt(ivBytes, keyBytes, Base64.decode(base64Text.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT));
    plainText = new String(cipherData, "UTF-8");
    Log.d("dcrypt", plainText);
```

I haven't tested it, but I think the code still works.

Comment: I noticed that if I copy my jdk9 code in new classes in my android application, it works. The problem is if I compile with jdk8. Seems that jdk9 code is portable with jdk7 but not with jdk8.

Comment: Oh all right, I have no idea so. It's weird a code running on jdk9 and 7 but not on jdk8.

Comment: Yes, it's a strange behaviour.

Comment: **Warning**: although this code shows that AES-256 works I would not copy the key usage, IV usage or exception handling. Using GCM instead of CBC should be considered for very secure code. I.e. use AES-256, but **do not use above code**.